# ESLint errors for missing prop types on an overridden render method

Tags: reactjs, eslint, formik

I am using `Formik` and overriding their `render` method to get some extra control over my `component`. I've used it before in another project, but in a new project, I am getting `errors` about `missing prop types`... but this is a Formik component, which has complete control over its own props, and I don't want to write `prop types` for it.
 I would rather not just disable ESLint on the line, as that is hacky and ugly.

Example:

```js
<Formik
    // other props ...
    render={(props) => {
        const { exampleFormikProp } = props;
        // I then use that prop in things
    }
/>
```

Problem: ESLint wants `exampleFormikProp` in props validation. It never complained about this in my old app. To me, this feels like an error. I shouldn't have to prop type something that Formik controls, I have no way of changing what Formik gives me here.

The only remotely related ESLint rules I have:

```js
'react/forbid-prop-types': 0,
'react/require-default-props': 0,
'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 0,
```

None of those seem relevant. I haven't been able to find any other example. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663177/eslint-proptype-issues-with-composed-render-props) seems like it could be related but has no answer.

How do I fix this?

To be clear, I want prop types to be required on components that I am creating, but I don't want them when overriding render in this method, as I don't think it's appropriate.

Example:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
    // I -want- to require prop-types for these props
    const { myCustomProps } = props;

    return (
        <Formik
            // I -don't- want to define prop-types for these, as that is inappropriate
            render={props => {...}}
        />
    );
}
```

*Update 10/1/19* - A temporary workaround seems to be renaming `props` to `formikProps` or some other term. I don't really like it, but it works. I'd still like an answer to the underlying problem, however.